# Cannot connect to internet using my modem

Tags: internet, modem

I have Windows xp professional in my pc.  I dual boot Ubuntu 18.4 with window xp.  Installation complete.  But now I am not able to connect to the Internet by using my Micromax modem in Ubuntu.  Please help. Thanks you in advance.  I am new to Ubuntu  .
This is the output on using command lsusb-

```
lsusb -t
/: Bus 07 .Port 1 : Dev 1,Class=root_hub; Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 06 .Port 1 : Dev 1,Class=root_hub; Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 05 .Port 1 : Dev 1,Class=root_hub; Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 04 .Port 1 : Dev 1,Class=root_hub; Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/___Port 1:Dev 4, If 0, Class = Mass Storage,  Driver =usb-storage, 12M
/___Port 2: Dev 3,If 0,Class =Human Interface Device, Driver =usbhid, 1.5 M
/: Bus 03 .Port 1 : Dev 1,Class=root_hub; Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 02 .Port 1 : Dev 1,Class=root_hub; Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
/: Bus 01 .Port 1 : Dev 1,Class=root_hub; Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
```

And on using command -

sudo lshw -C modem
SCSI

Comment: Is the modem a USB device? If yes, please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb -t`

Comment: I cannot upload image website is saying that i need ten reputation.  What to do now

Comment: Sorry for late response actually my exam started.  That's why I was not able to answer

Comment: You insert a link to the image, and someone with enough reputation will edit it in. If it's text, please do not add it as a picture, but see [this](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for how to include text in your question.

Comment: I have uploaded the output.  Please see if it helps

Comment: I hope you can understand where a new line start

Comment: Please format output from the terminal as **code** by using the { } icon above the edit window in the future.

Comment: Please post (as above) the results of `sudo lshw -C modem`

Comment: Waltinator First it shows  as USB and then SCSI